# Oracle Join: getting all values from table 2 for duplicates values in table 1

Tags: oracle, join

I hope the title above somewhat makes sense...

So I have one table with some duplicate in it:

```
Key

100
100
100
101
102
102
103
```

And a second table with non-duplicate keys and a corresponding indicator:

```
Key     Indicator

100        Y
101        N
102        Y
103        N
```

How would I do a join so that I get a return of table 1's duplicate Keys and the corresponding Indicator? So that...

```
Key     Indicator

100         Y
100         Y
100         Y
101         N
102         Y
102         Y
103         N
```

No matter how I join I continue to get duplicates.

Comment: You can use `select distinct` or `select columns from tables\joins group by columns`

Comment: I don't understand. Is the last table in your post the *desired* result, or is that something you can get, but it is not what you want? If so, what **do** you want?

Comment: Being more explicit `SELECT distinct tab1.key, tab2.Indicator FROM table1 tab1 INNER JOIN table2 tab2 ON tab2.key=tab1.key` or `SELECT tab1.key, tab2.Indicator FROM table1 tab1 INNER JOIN table2 tab2 ON tab2.key=tab1.key GROUP BY tab1.key, tab2.Indicator`, hope this helps.

Comment: Oops, you are right @mathguy, now that I look carefully at OP it's not clear what the problem is. I Just took last sentence as duplicates being the problem, however previously it's stated that he/she (Samuel / Samantha) wants the duplicate keys from table 1, which now raises a doubt for me too.

Comment: @JairHernandez Sorry for being unclear -- the last table is the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if last table is the desired result, then a simple JOIN has to do the trick:

```
SELECT tab1.key, tab2.Indicator
FROM table1 tab1
INNER JOIN table2 tab2 ON tab2.key = tab1.key
```

So that for every `key` in `table1` that has a match in `table2`, the row from `table1` will be presented with `indicator` of the matched `key` in `table2`. Next I present it with the data you originally posted:

```
select tab1.key, tab2.indicator
from (
        select 100 as key from dual
        union all
        select 100 as key from dual
        union all
        select 100 as key from dual
        union all
        select 101 as key from dual
        union all
        select 102 as key from dual
        union all
        select 102 as key from dual
        union all
        select 103 as key from dual ) tab1
inner join (    select 100 as key, 'Y' as indicator from dual
                union all
                select 101 as key, 'N' as indicator from dual
                union all
                select 102 as key, 'Y' as indicator from dual
                union all
                select 103 as key, 'N' as indicator from dual
            ) tab2 on tab2.key = tab1.key;
```

With result as:

```
KEY INDICATOR
--- ---------
100 Y
100 Y
100 Y
101 N
102 Y
102 Y
103 N
```